# Select Case with Chars with Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net

After setting on the **option strict** i get syntax errors in the following:

```
Select Case Me.oWorker.Relationship_Status
    Case "S"
        Me.opSingle.Checked = True
    Case "C"
        Me.opMarried.Checked = True
    Case "O"
        Me.opAnotherStatus.Checked = True
End Select
```

Compiler says that the option strict disallows implicit conversions fro String to Char. That Relationship_Status property of oWorker object is a Char of course.

How can I workaround this without changing the Relationship_status property to String? Do I really need to use CChar to Cast like this: CChar("S") ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a c after. This is the VB char syntax:

```
Select Case Me.oWorker.Relationship_Status 
    Case "S"c
        Me.opSingle.Checked = True 
    Case "C"c
        Me.opMarried.Checked = True 
    Case "O"c
        Me.opAnotherStatus.Checked = True
End Select
```

Comment: That's for C#, not VB.NET.

Comment: You're absolutely write. Corrected!

Comment: Sorry, first time using the SO Android app and I couldn't see the language tag.

Comment: Well what do you know. And I just wrote an answer too. :)

Comment: I had actually edited mine *before* I read your comment on my answer, and at that point it hadn't even loaded your answer.

Comment: Yes, yes. I'm not accusing you for copying me or something like that. I just thought it was fun that you corrected your answer at the same time that I posted mine.

Comment: I changed the 'C's to 'c' .

Comment: Accused or not, I wanted to make it clear I wouldn't just copy an answer. Kind of defeats the points of SO I think ^^

Comment: I was about the note... I don't believe you're restricted to lowercase C, and in the Microsoft documentation it actually specifies an uppercase C: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b.aspx

Comment: The IDE apparently chooses to change the uppercase to lower case.  Guess the writers of the IDE didn't read the docs. ;)

Comment: If I had enough reputation I would +1 that. The IDE guys have made a better choice. Though a shame the language guys couldn't have gone one better; I prefer the C#/Java syntax.

Comment: Thank you both for welcoming me into the community :)

Comment: VB.NET is case-insensitive, so upper-/lowercase `c` doesn't matter (although lowercase improves readability IMO). -- And yes, welcome to our amazing world! We have [unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns)!